# How can I implement componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate using the useEffect hook?

Tags: react-hooks

Please how can I implement exactly this code if I use the `useEffect` hook in a functional component?

```js
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.user.id !== prevProps.user.id) {
      this.setState({
        isLoggedIn: true,
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchConversations();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const {fetchConverstaions, user} = props

useEffect(() => {
   fetchConverstaions()
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
   setIsLoggedIn(true) //useState
}, [user?.id])
```

The `useEffect` with empty dependencies `[]` will only run once, hence, `componentDidMount`. The second `useEffect` will run whenever `user.id` changes in value.

Comment: Won't this array ```[user?.id]``` rather translate to ```user && user.id``` instead of simply monitoring when the user id changes? Could you please explain further? Thank you!

Comment: No, it monitors change in `id`. The `?` is called Optional Chaining. It saves against `null` or `undefined` user. For null/undefined user, React can't find value of id, so it throws an error. With optional chaining, React handles null/undefined object itself.

Answer (score 0):

From the React documentation - [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

> Tip
>
> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of >useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and ?>componentWillUnmount combined.

so in your case, you can add all the logics in the `useEffect` hook.